# Calling prototype method from another object

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is it possible to call another prototype method inside a prototype method ? Like below.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    let gui = new GUI();
    let App = new App(gui);
});

var App = function(gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
    this.init();
    return this;
};

App.prototype.init = function() {
    this.gui.test();
};

var GUI = function() {
    return this;
};

GUI.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log("Test");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to call something like this.

Best regards and thx for ur help

Comment: @KevinBoucher Since `test` is a method  on `this.gui`, `this.gui.test()` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can. The only reason your code doesn't work is that you are *shadowing* `App` on the 3rd line.

Working code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    let gui = new GUI();
    let app = new App(gui);
});

var App = function(gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
    this.init();
    return this;
};

App.prototype.init = function() {
    this.gui.test();
};

var GUI = function() {
    return this;
};

GUI.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log("Test");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lower case _a_ in _app_: `let app = new App(gui);`